# DNS entry to redirect constant url to changing directory name

Tags: redirects, dns, cloudflare

I have static content that is regularly updated that I'd like to maintain 100% up-time for when switching over to new content.

Ideally I'd like to provide a single url such as:

```
static.mydomain.com/tiles/
```

that actually redirects to something like

```
static.mydomain.com/tiles-2016-03-01/
```

then when I roll-out a fresh update I can quickly update the DNS record to redirect to the new files

```
static.mydomain.com/tiles-2016-04-28/
```

Is this possible with DNS alone? Perhaps there's an alternative non-DNS solution I can use?

BTW I have numerous tile sets so would prefer to host them all under static.mydomain.com.

At present I deploy my new content to

```
static.mydomain.com/tiles-NEW
```

I then rename the existing "tiles" to "tiles-OLD", followed by renaming "tiles-NEW" to "tiles". Unfortunately this process takes a while due to the huge number of files held under each directory, so renaming via FTP or the web based control panel (my only options) results in a fair amount of downtime. As the site is popular at least some users are always going to experience issues during my renaming process.

Also using a quick DNS change would allow me to quickly roll back to an older version of my files if a problem was discovered with the update.

I'm using [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) for my DNS if this has any relevance to potential solutions.

**Alternative Solution**

As this is outside the abilities of DNS I solved it using a simple web.config file on IIS (a .htaccess can be used instead on Apache):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="tiles">
          <match url="^tiles/(.*)" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="tiles-20160428/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: DNS does not redirect. It only ties a domain name to an IP address. There are some other DNS records for aliases, mail exchanges, etc. That is it.

Comment: I found someone mentioning the use of a TXT record, but provided very little detail and my understanding leaves a bit to be desired at present - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28294347/250254

Comment: As DNS is perhaps looking like the wrong place to look for a solution. I'll experiment and see if redirects are available to me through web.config settings on the Windows hosting plan.

Comment: DNS cannot do what you are asking it to do. It is not designed to.

Comment: As for Apache, you can use a redirect within .htaccess.

Comment: Oh. Windows. There should be something for you. I do not know Windows and IIS at all. Sorry. I used to, but so much has changed since I retired. I cannot even guess at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

A DNS (domain name server) record can only associate Internet numbers and domain names in different ways, such as an A (IPv4) record, AAAA (IPv6) record, and MX (mail server, where to send email to). You cannot give instructions through DNS, such as a 301 or 302 Redirect response, which is what I believe you're asking for. You are going to need to use a web server and/or a content language like Go/PHP to accomplish what you have set out to do.